# how to fix localization on xcode 5 after i delete all language

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I took a mistake. I deleted all localizations.
But I would like to use localizations. So I tried to add. But I couldn't.
When I added localization, Show following image.

When I deleted all
[image]
Tried to add some language
[image]
After adding
[image]

But 0 Files created.

How should I fix it..Let me know please.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `Localizable.strings` once again and localize the files you need to be localized (including Localizable.strings) using File inspector

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I could localize what i need to localize. but Base appears two times lick my question's image.

Comment: Delete one base. Automatically another one deleted

Comment: Do you have a storyboard?If so try to localize it by the above mentioned method

Comment: That may be the reason for showing two Base one for iPhone storyboard and other for iPad storyboard

Comment: But, First time to create a project, I saw only a Base. it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to 
**File -> Add File to "Project" and then add "Main.storyboard" and "InfoPlist.strings"**

[image]